# How can I obtain the USB audio stream from this USB device using PyUSB?

Tags: python, iphone, raspberry-pi, usb, pyusb

I'm trying to get the USB audio output from my iPhone and play it through the audio jack of my Raspberry Pi. I have posted at the bottom, the result from printing the USB dev object.

My understanding is that I need to send a control transfer read to the 1 config's isochronous audio interface which should fetch the audio stream, which could be outputted using PulseAudio, which I understand to be 0x80, so in PyUSB speak it should be something like:

```
dev.ctrl_transfer(0xc0, 0x80, 0, 0,"")
```

Or maybe not.. I'm still learning about USB, sorry for the nooby question!

```
                dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=int(vendor_id,16),idProduct=int(product_id,16))
                print dev
```

returns the following:

```
DEVICE ID 05ac:12a8 on Bus 001 Address 005 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x05ac
 idProduct              : 0x12a8
 bcdDevice              :  0x540 Device 5.4
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Apple Inc.
 iProduct               :    0x2 iPhone
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 fb54fcb6ee76100b65426172848e402bce8f5872
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x4
  CONFIGURATION 1: 500 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x27 (39 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x5 PTP
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xfa (500 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Image =====================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x3
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x6 Image
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
      ENDPOINT 0x83: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
  CONFIGURATION 2: 500 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x95 (149 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x3
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x2
   iConfiguration       :    0x6 iPod USB Interface
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xfa (500 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Audio =====================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x0
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x1 Audio
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
    INTERFACE 1: Audio =====================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x0
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x1 Audio
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
    INTERFACE 1, 1: Audio ==================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x1
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x1 Audio
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
       bLength          :    0x9 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0xc0 (192 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x4
    INTERFACE 2: Human Interface Device ====================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x2
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x3 Human Interface Device
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x83: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 3: 500 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x3e (62 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x2
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x3
   iConfiguration       :    0x7 PTP + Apple Mobile Device
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xfa (500 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Image =====================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x3
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x6 Image
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
      ENDPOINT 0x83: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
    INTERFACE 1: Vendor Specific ===========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xfe
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x2
     iInterface         :    0xc Apple USB Multiplexor
      ENDPOINT 0x4: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x4 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x85: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x85 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
  CONFIGURATION 4: 500 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x75 (117 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x3
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x4
   iConfiguration       :    0x8 PTP + Apple Mobile Device + Apple USB Ethernet
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xfa (500 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Image =====================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x3
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x6 Image
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
      ENDPOINT 0x83: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xa
    INTERFACE 1: Vendor Specific ===========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xfe
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x2
     iInterface         :    0xc Apple USB Multiplexor
      ENDPOINT 0x4: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x4 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x85: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x85 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
    INTERFACE 2: Vendor Specific ===========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x2
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x0
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xfd
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
     iInterface         :    0x0 
    INTERFACE 2, 1: Vendor Specific ========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x2
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x1
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xfd
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x86: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x86 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x5: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x5 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
    INTERFACE 2, 2: Vendor Specific ========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x2
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x2
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xfd
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x86: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x86 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x5: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x5 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
       bLength          :    0x9 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0xc0 (192 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x4
```

Comment: I'm now looking into iPod Accessory Protocol as I have been able to implement a dock with Android Accessory Protocol. Any tips?

Comment: My understanding is that I will have to sign up for MFi https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ for which you have to sign an NDA. Setting the same thing up for Android is very easy using AOA https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol.html . The key issue is that the raspberry Pi 3 cannot act as a slave device, so I can not use it as an amplifier with the plain USB audio class.